# How to deal with hide and show in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have the following HTML template.

```
<script type="text/template" id="friend-request-list">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
        <@ friendRequestCollection.each(function(user) { @>
            <li id="user-list-<@= user.get('username') @>"><a href="#"><@= user.get('firstName') @></a></li>
        <@ }); @>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This template is shown in the following pendingFriendRequest div,

```
<ul class="nav pull-left">
                    <li>
                      <div id="pendingFriendRequest" class="notired">${nbFriendRequest}</div><a href="#" class="notifriend"><i class="icon-eye-open icon-white"></i></a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
```

The backbone code is as follows

```
app.View.FriendRequestListView = Backbone.View.extend( {
template: _.template($('#friend-request-list').html()),

tagName: 'div',

initialize: function(){
    this.friendRequestCollection = new app.Collection.FriendRequestCollection();
    this.friendRequestCollection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    this.friendRequestCollection.fetch();

    var self = this;
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        friendRequestCollection: this.friendRequestCollection}));
    return $(this.el);
}

});

 app.Collection.FriendRequestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url : function(){
      return '/rest/friendRequests';
   }
  });
```

But now what i wanted is that the list should be invisible and only when the link is clicked the list is displayed as a menu. On clicking somehwere else or if the cursor is moved to somewhere else the menu must hide.

IS this possible. I am newbie in backbone so dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use common `javascript&jQuery` functions: `.show()`&`.hide()` or `.addClass()`&`removeClass()` with `your_menu_div`. You can write all events ,which you need, like that:

```
app.View.FriendRequestListView = Backbone.View.extend( {
  initialize: function(options){
    // it works when you click another place
    $('html').off()
    $('html').on('click', $.proxy(function(){ 
      menuElem = @$el.find('.nav-stacked');
      if !menuElem.hasClass('hidden')
        menuElem.addClass('hidden');}));
  },

  events: {
    'mouseleave .row-fluid': '_hideMenuContent',
    'mouseenter .row-fluid': '_showMenuContent'
    //other events
  },

  _hideMenuContent: function() {
    if ( !@$el.find('.nav-stacked').hasClass('hidden') )
    @leave = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(@leave) 
        @leave = false; 
        @$el.find('.nav-stacked').addClass('hidden');}
    , 3000);  
  },

  _showMenuContent: function() {
    if ( !@$el.find('.nav-stacked').hasClass('hidden') )
    @leave = false;
  }
});
```

But you need to think about your app architecture, because `your_menu_div` had to be inside `app.View.FriendRequestListView.el`. The div can be '.row-fluid'

Comment: You can use [`@$(x)` (AKA `this.$(x)`)](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) instead of `@$el.find(x)` or `this.$el.find(x)`.

Comment: @muistooshort - Yes, You are right, but by `@$el.find(x)` I wanted to prove the `x` had to be inside `el` container

Comment: Is there a technical reason `$('html').off()` is there? If you had multiple views like this on the page you might not want **all** events to be removed. Perhaps an event namespace would be better (`$('html').off('.myView')`).